# double quote charater (’"’) with listings create problem

Tags: characters, strings

I have don't know how to fix the double quote character (’"’) with the listing package. Listing get this as the beginning of a string but it is not.

Here is the colored minimal example to show the problem :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\lstset{
  language=Bash,
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  commentstyle=\color{green},
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
    file_name=$(cut -d '"' -f 2)
    # This shoud be a comment
    echo "This should be a String"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Results in :

[image]

Thanks for any help !

Edit :  Note that if I replace the double quote character by the letter a, the coloration is working well :

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I guess that the quotes `‘` are creating the problem, rather than `"`.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me ! Yes in fact I would like to escape the character between the quote but I don't know how to do that ;)

Comment: The output here seems to be as-expected...

Comment: i'm a bit confused here, as an answer has already been accepted that i would have thought not what was really wanted.  what i would have expected is that the double quote should be the "ditto", or straight double quote, unicode U+0022, whereas what's given in the answer is the right double quote, U+201D.  if it's really the straight quote, i know an approach that works with the "typewriter" font, and could try to adapt it to be used with `lstlisting`.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I don't really care about which unicode double quote character is used. I accepted the answer as it solves what I care about : I want the comment to appear in green and I want the String to appear in red. I apologies for being not clear in first place.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Please post your answer, I’m interested too! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `moredelim`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\lstset{
  language=bash,
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  commentstyle=\color{green},
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  moredelim=[s]'',
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
    file_name=$(cut -d '"' -f 2)
    # This shoud be a comment
    echo "This should be a String"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output of the code]

Or maybe `morestring` is more appropriate.  In bash, is `'` escaped via `\` or by doubling it?  I guess via `\`:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\lstset{
  language=bash,
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  commentstyle=\color{green},
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  morestring=[b]',
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
    file_name=$(cut -d '"' -f 2)
    # This shoud be a comment
    echo "This should be a String"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of second example]

Comment: This is exactly the kind of solution I am looking for :)

Comment: Unfortunately, my minimal example seems to be incomplete : I need to include existing code.

Comment: Is there a way to have morestring or moredelim working with included file ?

Comment: \lstinputlisting[language=bash]{test.sh}

Comment: i justed changed the example by moving the code in a separate test.sh file

Comment: and now the fix with morestring / moredelim isn't working anymore :'(

Comment: @Marc: If you repeat the choice of the language in the optional argument of `\lsttinputlisting`, you must repeat the patch as well: `\lstinpulistings[language=bash,morestring{[b]'}]{…}` (note the additional pair of braces; but it is just simpler to say `\lstinputlisting{…}`.  EDIT: I would say this is a bug in the definition of the `bash` language, anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! Unfortunately I don't succeed in making this work with an included file so I just created a new question : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252516/listings-moredelim-morestring-options-doesnt-work-with-included-file