# Listings moredelim / morestring options doesn't work with included file

Tags: listings, include

I don't know how to fix the double quote character (’"’) with the listings package when the code is in a separated file. Listing get this as the beginning of a string but it is not.

Many thanks to Gustavo Mezzetti for his answer with the moredelim/morestring options. Unfortunately even if thoses fixes are working well inside a latex file, morestring and moredelim fixes don't work when I include the code from a separated file.

Here is the new minimal example to show the problem :

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\lstset{
  language=bash,
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  commentstyle=\color{green},
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  morestring=[b]',
}

\begin{document}
This is working fine thanks to Gustavo Mezzetti answer's and the morestring=[b]' option :

\begin{lstlisting}
file_name=$(cut -d '"' -f 2)
# This shoud be a comment
    echo "This should be a String"
\end{lstlisting}

This isn't working anymore when the same code is included from a separated file :

\lstinputlisting[language=Bash, morestring{[b]'}]{test.sh}
\end{document}
```

With the following separated file "test.sh" :

```
  file_name=$(cut -d '"' -f 2)
  # This shoud be a comment
  echo "This should be a String"
```

Results in :

[image]

Thanks for any help !

Note that this question is following this one :
[double quote charater (’"’) with listings create problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252443/double-quote-charater-with-listings-create-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I get the fix : I just need to replace

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Bash, morestring{[b]'}]{test.sh}
```

By

```
\lstinputlisting{test.sh}
```

The redundancy of listings options was the problem here I guess ;)

Comment: I cannot refrain from observing that the code you posted doesn’t work simply because it contains a syntax error: `\lstinputlisting[language=bash, morestring={[b]'}]{test.sh}` (note the `=` after `morestrings`) works just fine for me.

Comment: I checked the previous question, and saw that it is my fault: the typo was already in my suggestion!

Comment: Thanks again for your analyzed answer Gustavo ! I think you have the right answer for this question too : the problem here was this option syntax error in the \lstinputlisting[language=bash, morestring={[b]'}]{test.sh} line ! I just copied/pasted without checking what I was doing !

Comment: As I have already said, this looks like a deficiency in the definition of the bash language: text delimited by single quotes _is_ kind of an instance of a string in shell scripts, isn’t it?  BTW, you might also want to try replacing, in the `\lstset` command, `morestring=[b]'` with `morestring=[b][\color{magenta}]'` (say).